# Is it possible to inspect a Meteor/Cordova iOS app?

Tags: ios, cordova, debugging, meteor

I came across [this](http://gonzalo123.com/2014/08/04/debugging-android-cordovaphonegap-apps-with-chrome/) article detailing how to debug an Android Cordova app using Chrome's developer tools. Considering an iOS app is also built on webkit is it possible to use a modern browser's developer tools to inspect a Meteor + Cordova app built and installed onto iOS and if so, how would one go about doing this?

Comment: You can do this with Safari: i.e. check http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html or http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-ios/

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed very easy to debug an app built with Meteor and Cordova using Safari's dev tools. The way I did it is to run the `meteor run ios` command to start your app in the iOS simulator. After that all I had to do was, making sure that the developer console was enabled in Safari settings, go to the Develop tab in Safari and pick my app from the Simulator device menu.